# Limits on contract work without pre-agreed price/contract (UK)

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

Say you hire someone, such as an electrician or plumber, without price even being mentioned by either party. The contractor later bills you: you're taken aback by the price. Maybe the expected rate is £100 and you get charged £1000. More fool you, right? Fair enough.

But is there any practical limit in English law? £1,000,000, your house? Is there any reasonableness limit in law?

Comment: No, this isn't a pickle I find myself in personally!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a reasonableness limit, and this is especially true in consumer transactions.

> If you were given an estimate and the final bill is a lot more than 
>   what you were expecting, you can dispute it.
>
> The final price should be ‘reasonable’. The law doesn’t say what
>   counts as reasonable, so you’ll have to agree it between you. You
>   should consider:
>
> - the estimate you agreed to [if there was one]
> - any changes, and why they happened
> - anything that happened that was beyond the control of the trader, 
>     like bad weather or the cost of materials going up

https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/consumer/getting-home-improvements-done/problem-with-home-improvements/

> When it comes to work itself, the act states that a tradesman or
>   professional has a 'duty of care' towards you and your property. Any
>   standard or price you agree must be honoured. But if it isn't agreed
>   in advance the work must be done to a reasonable standard, at a
>   reasonable cost, and within a reasonable time.
>
> So if you haven't fixed a price, you don't have to pay a ridiculously
>   high bill. All you have to pay is what you consider 'reasonable' and
>   invite them to sue you for the rest. Be careful though, in some
>   circumstances when you are withholding payment you may have a claim
>   made against you by a supplier if you are in breach of contract.
>   **What's a reasonable amount would be what similar tradesmen would have
>   charged for the job.** So get a few quotations.

https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/1fdlwC9xzyxjCpWMlsCGG3j/supply-of-services

NB that article refers to The Supply of Goods & Services Act 1982, which was partially superseded by the Consumer Rights Act 2015.

Answer (score -4):

The contractor can charge what he wants, but if you are worried about it you can ask him to only preform services costing under million pound amount or whatever.

Comment: What happens when the contractor goes: "I have done a million points worth of work. I hope you enjoy that one door I installed."

Comment: You talk to them before hand.